# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.1 file sharing

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, ubuntu-18.04

Dual boot with Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Dell XPS came with Ubuntu native. I added the dual boot with media Microsoft sent. I was able to partition and install. When the Windows installed, it could not detect a network? Internet still works fine on Ubuntu. Need Windows for work. I have DLed the driver I think I need in Ubuntu, but have no way to get it over to Windows. Is there a way to do it in Ubuntu? I am very new to this.

Comment: One way to do this, without risking the integrity of either file system, is to copy the file to an external USB drive. But have you checked Device Manager? Windows has the drivers for most interfaces: does DM show an error for the interface? Try powering off Windows (not shutting down, which by default hibernates), then removing power and battery for 30 seconds. This makes sure that the interface starts from cold: I've occasionally needed to do this when switching between Ubuntu and Win10, which I put down to the hardware being left by one OS in a state that the other OS driver can't handle.

Comment: Which of my suggestions was the fix? Powering off, or importing via USB?

Comment: Yes. Since the partition already had Windows on it, that was the way I managed to get the appropriate driver there. Had a brief issue powering down from Windows this morning, but I managed to by removing the battery and haven't had issues since! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Windows, disable its fast startup feature. Nowit's "safe" to mount the Windows drive in Ubuntu with read/write permissions.

Reboot to Ubuntu, open the file manager and click on the Windows drive to mount it. Now you can copy/move the driver files to your Windows partition. Avoid writing or changing anything else outside your (Windows) user's space (suggestion: Copy/Move the files to your user's downloads folder in Windows).

This answer is provided for your convenience only and to solve a specific problem. Please avoid doing this routinely. If you need to shares files between Windows and Ubuntu in the same drive **use a separated data partition (NTFS).**